# Linear Transformation for Ker(T) and Range(T)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the linear transformation $T: P_3 \to P_3$ given by

> $ T(p(t)) = p(t) + p(2-t) $

Find a basis for the $Ker(T)$ and $Range(T)$.

So a standard basis for the $P_3$ is  {$1,t,t^2,t^3$}

So $ T(p(t)) = T(at^3+bt^2+ct+d) = at^3+bt^2+ct+d+(2-t)^3(a)+(2-t)^2(b)+(2-t)(c)+d$

The $Ker(T)$ = {$T(p)= 0/ p \in  P_3$}

I don't know where to go from here. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate $T$ at the basis elements . Then we can see that the outcome is:

$T(1) = 1 + 1 = 2$

$T(t) = t + (2-t) = 2$

$T(t^2) = t^2 + (2-t)^2 = 2t^2 - 4t + 4$

$T(t^3) = 6t^2 - 12t+8$

So, you have to find $a,b,c,d$ such that : $a(6t^2 + 12t+8) + b(2t^2 - 4t+4) + 2c+2d = 0$. Then, $at^3+bt^2+ct+d \in \ker(T)$.

To find the kernel, first split into components (comparing coefficients of $t$, which all have to be zero since the RHS is zero):
$$
6a+2b = 0 ; 12a-4b = 0; 8a+4b+2c+2d = 0
$$ 
Then we see that $3a = -3a$, so $a=b=0$, and $c+d = 0$.

So the only polynomials satisfying this property are of the form $c(t-1)$, where $c$ is a real number, and a basis is given by $t-1$ in that case.

For the range, note that if we introduce a free variable $e = 2c+2d$, then the range is made of $a(6t^2 + 12t+8) + b(2t^2 - 4t+4) + e(1)$, where $a,b,e$ vary freely. You can check that $\{1, 2t^2-4t+4,6t^2+12t+8\}$ are linearly independent, and it's clear they span the range, so they form a basis  for the range.

Comment: I think it should be $ -12a-4b = 0$

Comment: So the \begin{bmatrix}
        6 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
        -12 & -4 & 0 & 0 \\
        8 & 4 & 2 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
and then that should reduce to 

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -1/2 & -1/2 \\
        0 & 1 & 3/2 & 3/2 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

And then the basis for the $Ker(T)$ should be {$-1/2t^3-3/2t^2+t, 1/2t^3-3/2t^2+1$} wouldn't it?

Comment: @NTT Thank you for the correction, and yes, the basis should be as you have written.